# Anyone tried to brush mud/snow in rear-wheel while on ride?

Tags: diy, fenders, snow

I ride my bike in the snow. And I think my bike can be a lot cleaner if I had a snow catcher in my rear-wheel.

There is possibility because the rear wheel fork comes with extra holes in it. I think we can hook a fork there to hold a brush at the back of the tire.

I think it will keep the gear and derailleur cleaner. I guess it will also reduce the skidding.

Comment: Are you wanting to clean the tyre of snow, or do you want to keep the bike cleaner?

Comment: @Criggie Both. When my tire gets snow it obstructs in the v-brake and drop the snow on my gear and derailleur . Snow wrapped tire also has less traction .

Comment: I would suggest you modify your riding style, and stop riding through the snow.  Instead, ride in wheel tracks or whereever else the snow is thinner.   Self-cleaning treads might help as well - they have more slope-sided blocks than square blocks.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer not using anything in the snow to block the snow. You risk the snow packing in the snow blocker (e.g. fenders) and freezing, which can be dangerous. A brush against the tire (depending on the stiffness of the bristles) could also damage your tire.

If you want to use something, a seatpost fender and a downtube mudguard are probalby the safest options.

If you want to keep your bike clean in winter, good luck (especially if you ride on salted roads). The best course of action is to bring it in when you have time (e.g. 24 hours), clean the bike indoors, let it be completely dry then take it back out. Or, if theres a warm day, do a quick (light) wipe down and dry the bike off as you go. You could also try a stiff brush which may get rid of some of the salt.  Or just deal with a dirty bike, and clean it in the spring.

Comment: Or get a beater bike specifically for the winter months. The aluminum BSO mountain bikes are particularly good for this.

Answer (score 4):

I thought I've seen something like this before... so I googled a bit and found traces of this [design](http://hiconsumption.com/2014/08/denny-bicycle-the-bike-of-the-future-teague-sizmore/), apparently deceased.

[image: Rain brush fender]

While it looks clever, I have some doubts that it will work efficiently for any real rain. As soon as the brush is "saturated" with water, incoming drops will cause some of already collected water to detach and continue its way up.

It will definitely not work for snow, the reason being the snow is hard not liquid. I had my rear wheel fully blocked many times when a build-up of snow formed in the chainstay-seattube-bottom bracket area of my bikes. Even a rear fender placed too low once caused such snow accumulation resulting in inability to rotate the rear wheel. Placing another hinder somewhere can only shift the position of such build-up or even provoke it.

Maybe some oil on tires might help to repel snow sticking to the tire, but obviously the same oil will hurt your braking capabilities to the extent that it will be safer to leave the bike home. However, you may try to use some bike  polish on the frame and on the drivetrain parts. It is told to help with preventing mud sticking to the frame; however, I used it and did not notice any measurable effects.

Solutions that I consider to work are:

- having another bicycle with a different braking system, preferably internal (say, drum) or even disk will work better;
- wider clearance between tires and the frame — if you can move your rear wheel in the dropouts further back;
- gnarlier tires, possibly spiked if you need to deal with plenty of ice; if not, just go with regular non-completely slick tires.
- just dealing with the fact that riding in the winter has to be done more carefully and slowly;
- just dealing with the fact that you will not be able to pass on your bike to your descendants; or maybe you actually will — bikes are survival tools and may last surprisingly long.

Comment: I like you mentioned and understood the v-brake problem in snow. It catches and cuts the snow. I think we can put a wire to cut extra snow instead of brush in your shared idea.

Comment: Or what about a long-back fender with heater in it.

Comment: You will need a ridiculously huge and heavy battery to power any sort of a heater, especially capable melting the ice, working for a reasonable period of time. Remember that the energy required to melt water/ice per kilogram is one of the highest among substances. And you will need it all the way around the wheel, otherwise just melted water will freeze into real ice immediately after it leaves the heated zone.

Comment: On a wire: remember that it is not only snow that will be pushed by wire, but also the the wire pushed by snow. If you use a thin wire, it will flex back and will be of no use, or will even break. If you use a thick wire, it will start accumulating snow just like the rest of the rear frame parts. But you definitely can try, it won't hurt, at least much. Good luck, and I am off to enjoyng riding in the snow now!